# How to get this y and z while using with flatlist?

Tags: react-native, exp

```
<FlatList
  data={[{y: 'a'}, {z: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text></Text>}
/>
```

here I'm using `x` and `y` as `timestamp` and I need to get this timestamp and the timestamp value.

Comment: It would be enough to read documentation. The thing you are asking is very basic stuff.
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Briefly: 

<FlatList
    data={[{y: 'a'}, {z: 'b'}]} // <--- Why you have different objects in your 
    data? It's better to have one type of objects in your array.
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text></Text>} <---- You have all data about your objects in `item` variable. That's the point.
/>

Comment: So using different keys is not possible?